Is there a way to split exchange body (list) into chuncks instead of one-element exchanges?
Is there a way to split body of exchange (List) into bigger chuncks than 1 element exchanges?
When using big files to process, i end up with huge number of one-line exchanges and alot of memory consumption.
       from(url.concat("RAW(" + filesToInclude + ")"))
                .log("Start processing file: ${header.CamelFileName}")
                .routeId(CamelRoutes.LIST_ROUTE_ID + endpointConfig.getConfigId())
                .setHeader(CamelHeaders.ENDPOINT_CONFIG, constant(endpointConfig))

                .unmarshal(getCsvDataFormat(endpointConfig))

                .split(body())
                    .streaming().parallelProcessing().executorService(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(CONCURRENT_THREADS_NUMBER))
                    .stopOnException().stopOnAggregateException()
                    .marshal().json(JsonLibrary.Jackson)
                    .log("Starting aggregating for batch processing")
                    .aggregate(header(Exchange.FILE_NAME), new ListAggregationStrategy())
                        .completionPredicate(new BatchSizePredicate(endpointConfig.getMaxBatchSize()))
                        .completionTimeout(endpointConfig.getBatchTimeout())
                        .log("Start one batch processing")
                        .bean(rowCamelService, "saveInDB")
                        .log("Finished one batch processing")
                    .end()
                    .log("Finished aggregating for batch processing")
                    .log("Finished processing file: ${header.CamelFileName}")
                .end();

For 60MB of CSV file, it takes over 1G or memory.
I need to lower it down to 500MB at maximum.

Please [edit] the post and clarify what a "reasonable value" is. --- I do no think that we can get under 600 MB (since this is the file size and camel "constructs" the whole exchange with the full body first).

Well, the file is 60MB. I would assume that it will take less than 3x like that so lets set 500MB as max but currently it jumps to about 2G. Also when camel takes more than 1 file at once, it results in OOM error...

My bad. I read "600 MB" instead of "60 MB"

You use setBody(...) to partition the list before splitting
public class MyRouteBuilder extends RouteBuilder {
   private static final int BATCH_SIZE = 1000;

   private <T> List<List<T>> splitIntoBatches(List<T> list, int batchSize) {
      // TODO implement using one of the suggestions from https://www.baeldung.com/java-list-split
   }

   public void configure() {
      from(...)
         .setBody(exchange -> {
            List<String> list = exchange.getMessage().getBody(List.class);
            return splitIntoBatches(list, BATCH_SIZE);
         })
         .split(body())
         .streaming()
         ...
   }
}


Nice! Thanks :) Memory consumption dropped to <1G :) Just needed to also remove aggregation.

Note you could use Iterables instead of Lists to further reduce memory requirements
